# Spring Data JPA OneToMany Relationship weird error

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data

i have 2 entities which look like this:

```
@Entity(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String username;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Option> options = new ArrayList<>();
    getters and setters...

@Entity
public class Option {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private int option;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
    setters and getters
```

Also, i have those properties in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbtest
spring.datasource.username=something
spring.datasource.password=something
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Every time i run the application it gives me this:

```
Error executing DDL "create table option (id integer not null, option integer not null, user_id integer, primary key (id)) engine=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
```

I don't understand what i'm doing wrong :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use table with name Option and user because it is statement in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

`option` is a reserved word in MySql. Try to use a different name for your attribute and table.